# Is it possible to prevent Windows to reset many system settings to default after a major update (Fall Creators Update)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, device-manager, wake-up, energy-saving

I recently installed the Windows 10 Creators Update on many of my PCs, and as with previous "major" update releases, I noticed that many of the system settings, including things like:

- Energy options in device manager ("allow device to wake the computer from  sleep"
  re-enabled for mice and keyboards which is annoying because I
  intentionally turned these off)
- basic mode of displaying the taskmanager and many more get reset to
  their defaults.

Since major updates are coming approximately twice a year, I was wondering: why does Windows do that, and is there a way to turn this behavior off? It is especially annoying if you install a computer for a novice user, and after an update you have to redo all these customization steps again.

On the other hand, many things like explorer settings stay the same, for example things like "show hidden files" or "show file extensions".

So the main questions are:

- which settings are reset after an update, and what's the criteria behind that selection, where others aren't?
- is there a list of the things that are reset during a 
  major update for reference?

Comment: This is a combination of opinion-based ("why are ...") and too-broad ("is there a complete list ..."). You should try and fix this if you want your question to stay open.

Comment: Someone at Microsoft decides to do it that way. And he doesn’t bother to give a list, or reasons for it.